# How to call indicators into my strategy (Pine-Script) (Tradingview)

Tags: pine-script, trading, indicator

I wanted to use the Relative Vigor Index as part of my trading strategy, but I can't seem to be able to call/referrence it, even though it's a built-in tradingview indicator. I've tried using its full name (`RelativevigorIndex`)
and I've tried shortening it to `RVI`, as well as `RVGI`.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Not all built in chart indicators have built in functions in pine. You will have to load the code for the built in indicator (from the pine editor : Open / Open default built-in script) and manually incorporate the code into your strategy script.